# Is this question really "too localized?"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, too-localized

A moderator recently closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10651284/497356) as too localized. I disagree. I think there is enough information here (code, error message, link to relevant plugin being used) that it *is* likely to help visitors in the future. Could someone explain the rationale for closing here and correct me if my line of thinking is incorrect?

**Edit:** It's been re-opened now which is great, but any discussion as to why it was closed to begin with would be awesome.

Comment: Did you vote to re-open?

Comment: @YannisRizos: Of course! `:)`

Comment: Cool, I don't see what's localized about it, then again just a few minutes ago I was bragging on the phone that I hadn't touched JavaScript for almost a year (yes, that's a good thing).

Comment: [Guess what](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10651284/revisions): > Post Reopened by Andrew Whitaker, Dave DeLong, RoToRa, Lucifer, Dennis

Comment: I too vote to open, and it is opened now :)

Comment: FYI: Now the question is reopened, I have edited out the "update" message to avoid new confusion. It already has a new "too localized" close vote.

Comment: Looks like this has been dredged uo by a user answering here instead of the question. Interestingly this question is now closed again as too localised. I still dont think it is too localised, and so have yet again cast a reopen vote.

Comment: BTW, there's a distinct difference between "a moderator" and five people voting to close.

Comment: @casperOne: Actually it *was* closed by a moderator the first time. It's since been closed and reopened by the community.

Comment: @ɹǝʞɐʇıɥʍʍǝɹpuɐ Dammit, something funky is going on on meta.  Lot's of old crap being dredged up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what I could gather the problem was due to a typo as evidenced in this deleted answer and the comment attached:

[image]

..and OP also added the following to the question:

> **Updated:**
>
> > Typo error `require` changed to `required`. [ My mistake ]

This suggested that the cause of his difficulties was in fact the "typo" and it wasn't made abundantly clear by the OP that a problem still remained unsolved.

So I closed it as Too Localised.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain

Comment: Hey, Guys.. the typo was in the question. It didn't resolved the problem. There has been a confusion. That is why the person deleted his answer - since that was not the issue !

Answer (score 8):

The last update was extremely confusing. At first glance, I thought the problem was solved by correcting a typo, only after looking at the question several times did I realize that the typo existed *in the question* but perhaps not in the *code being run*.

That's probably why it was closed, since causes like *I had a typo in a [something]* are not likely to provide solutions to future visitors. I'm not the mod that closed it, but I probably would have if I was the one that serviced the flag.

The last edit needs a bit of clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the rationale for closing as too localized is the following (though only @Kev can confirm I guess):

Note how the OP states:

> Typo error require changed to required. [ My mistake ]

So the problem might seem to be resolved (and was based on a simple mistake). Therefor someone might have flagged the question as in "Not much point to leave it open now since it's resolved" and the closest closure reason would be "too localized". I have flagged similar cases like that myself where the issue was actually resolved, therefor this speculation.

Whether the problem was actually resolved, or whether this was merely a comment that should have gone into the edit-reason, I don't know. It's at the very least confusing if the question is not answered.